# Trigger Clicked Event of Button in Maui

Tags: .net, maui, .net-8.0, maui-windows

My platform is Windows.

Is it possible that I can trigger Clicked event in code?

In WPF, I was using RaisEvent to do it.

Like:

```
public void TriggerClickedEvent(UIElement element)
{
    element.RaiseEvent(
        new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Middle)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent,
            Source = element
        });
    element.RaiseEvent(
        new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Middle)
        {
            RoutedEvent = Mouse.PreviewMouseUpEvent,
            Source = element
        });
    element.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
}
```

But I have no idea how to do it In Maui.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned <Button Clicked=""/> and <Button Command=""/> in MVVM are the only ways. In code behind: `button.Clicked += async (sender, args) => await label.RelRotateTo(360, 1000);` [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/button?view=net-maui-8.0) but you'd still have to actually click the button to activate it. You may want to use [DataTriggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/triggers?view=net-maui-8.0#data-triggers) to make more things happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern to trigger the click event by writing a View Model with a command that performs whatever the logic would be done when clicking the Button. The **ViewModel** defines properties of type `ICommand` that are then connected to Button objects with data bindings. .NET MAUI also defines Command and Command classes that implement the `ICommand` interface and assist the viewmodel in defining properties of type `ICommand`.

Here's the sample below for your reference:

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonDemos"
             x:Class="ButtonDemos.BasicButtonCommandPage"
             Title="Basic Button Command">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:CommandDemoViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='Value is now {0}'}"
               FontSize="18"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Multiply by 2"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Command="{Binding MultiplyBy2Command}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class CommandDemoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    double number = 1;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ICommand MultiplyBy2Command { get; private set; }
   
    public CommandDemoViewModel()
    {
        MultiplyBy2Command = new Command(() => Number *= 2);
    }

    public double Number
    {
        get => number;

        set
        {
            if (number != value)
            {
                number = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```